# Base Address for End Points in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, endpoint

I am using WCF and want to create 3 end points: basicHttpBinding, netTcpBinding and wsHttpBinding.
I have specified 2 endpoints as follows:

```
<endpoint address="StringManipulationService" binding="basicHttpBinding"
    contract="StringManipulationService.IStringManipulation" />
  <endpoint address="StringManipulationService" binding="netTcpBinding"
    contract="StringManipulationService.IStringManipulation" />
```

and specified base addresses as follows:

```
    <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/" />
      <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8090/" />
    </baseAddresses>
```

however I do not know how to write the base address for a wsHttpBinding and could not find it anywhere. Any help please. Thank you.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734786(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thank you. I thought there might be a similar structure to use as the others but guess not. the link helped. I have it working now. I used:

    <appSettings>  
    <add key="baseAddress" value="http://localhost:8000" />  
   </appSettings> 

and:

       <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        contract="StringManipulationService.IStringManipulation" />

Comment: I fought with WCF configs often enough, it really is annoying. Since you figured it out yourself, you could/should answer your own question here, which is encouraged at SO. That'll make it easier for others to see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <appSettings> 
      <add key="baseAddress" value="localhost:8000"; /> 
 </appSettings> 



 <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"
 contract="StringManipulationService.IStringManipulation" />
```